# More than one horizontal TSplitter in an FMX window/panel

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

My FMX app has three vertically stacked resizable panels sharing two horizontal TSplitters.

How can I have a TSplitter resize only the panels directly above and below the splitter?

Comment: I have never used FMX, but cannot you just let the top panel be `Align = alTop`, the middle one `alClient`, and the bottom one `alBottom`? Then the splitters will have the effect you describe.

Comment: Yes, that works. Now I'm trying to figure out how to get four panels managed by three splitters.